# multidimensional Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is my output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [count] => 3
            [TYPE] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 9
            [TYPE] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [TYPE] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 0
            [TYPE] => 4
        )

)
```

I got the above array 
now i m calling this function like this

```
$totalJobsCount = $model->GetStatus($data->id);
```

now i want the value of [0][count],[1][count],[2][count],[3][count]
so i m writing like this

```
$a = $totalJobsCount[0]['count'];

$a1 = $totalJobsCount[1]['count'];

$a2 = $totalJobsCount[2]['count'];

$a3 = $totalJobsCount[3]['count'];
```

but i got errr that undefined offset 0
where is prblem plz help me soon 
thanks in advance

Comment: Be sure to use quotes around the text array key (e.g., `$totalJobsCount[0]['count']`); otherwise it will try to look for a constant named "count" first.

Comment: `$totalJobsCount[0]['count'];` write count between quotes

Comment: ya that also done quotation but solution not coming :(

Comment: Yeah I thought it was the above too at first, but that gives a different error message. The error message you're getting says that index 0 does not exist, which is strange since the above shows that it is.

Comment: When did you do your var_dump of $totalJobsCount?

Comment: If i am writeing var_dump();array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "9"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["TYPE"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
}

Comment: Yeah, that's very strange. Looks the 0 index exists. If you remove the line where you get the 0 job count, do you get a similar error with index 1?

Comment: Just curious, but could you update the question with your GetStatus method?

Answer (score 0):

```
         $det = array( array( Title => "rose", 
                  Price => 1.25
                ),
           array( Title => "daisy", 
                  Price => 0.75
                ),
           array( Title => "orchid", 
                  Price => 1.15
                )
         );

         print_r($det);

          echo $det[0]['Title'];
```

"rose" in  $det[0]['Title']

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will get better answers if you ask a more clear answer, and post executable code which demonstrates your problem.

The `Array(...)` dump at the top of your question isn't executable code. It would help if you would replace it by code which runs and generates that data structure.  I've given an example below.

Read the PHP documentation on [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) carefully. Are you following what it says there?

Exactly which line is causing the error?  Can you simplify your code so that there are no function calls involved, and it is exactly the last line which triggers the error?  Doing this exercise might help you find out your answer.

Others have already pointed out that you were using unquoted strings in both your array dump and array lookup expressions. The problem with that is that the name [`count`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) refers to a function, so in some contexts PHP could interpret it that way. I suspect that you are using the unquoted string `count` somewhere in building up your array, and that is causing the problem.

The code sample below, which I've tested at [codepad](http://codepad.org/TOr9s2AQ), demonstrates that multidimensional arrays in PHP do behave as expected, when strings are quoted, and even sometimes when strings aren't quoted.

```
<? $totalJobsCount = Array
(Array(
            'count' => 3,
            'TYPE' => 1
        ),
 Array(
            count => 9,
            TYPE => 2
        ),
Array(
            'count' => 0,
            'TYPE' => 3
        ),
Array(
            'count' => 0,
            'TYPE' => 4
        )

); 
var_dump( $totalJobsCount );

print '$totalJobsCount[0][\'count\'] = '.$totalJobsCount[0]['count']."\n";
print '$totalJobsCount[1][count] = '.$totalJobsCount[1][count]."\n";
?>
```

The above code yields the following result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(9)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(0)
    ["TYPE"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
$totalJobsCount[0]['count'] = 3
$totalJobsCount[1][count] = 9
```